# Making custom axe, shovel and hoe work as intended. Strip logs, till land, make paths?

Tags: minecraft-bedrock-edition, minecraft-addons

This question involves trying to figure out how to have my custom tools (specifically the axe, shovel, and hoe) do their intended "special" function (I guess that is what they're called).  The axe will not do anything if I try to strip logs, the axe doesn't even move.  The hoe and shovel are the same, so if anyone might have any suggestions that would be great.

Comment: Can you try to add your code (or at least tell us what you've done so far)? That might help you get an answer.

Comment: *A preliminary prototype*: try it out and see if it does what you want https://www.mediafire.com/file/f39won5lwc9dmvm/CustomTools_Updated.zip/file **If so**, maybe you would be interested in writing your own answer based on the parts you end up using. (The relevant changes will be in the `main.js` file and the tools' `item.json` files.) Here is the info page for answering one's own question: https://gaming.stackexchange.com/help/self-answer

Comment: Are you using the addon for singleplayer, or on a multiplayer server? If it is intended for multiplayer, some slight modifications will have to be made to avoid conflicts when more than one player is using the same item. I'll add this fix to the finished version of the template addon, which I'll be posting on Planet Minecraft (tomorrow?).

Comment: It is intended to be used for multiplayer with my friends.  If the version you updated will work for that then after I test it I will post an answer so that anyone sle with the same/similar issues will be able to try it, also it will give me the chance to try out that feature.

Comment: New working version for 1.10.0-beta, which should be compatible with multiplayer: https://www.planetminecraft.com/texture-pack/custom-tools-template-full-functionality-requires-beta-apis-toggle/